# Does the water level rise?

Tags: pressure, fluid-statics

if I have A closed vessel that is half-filled with water. There is a hole near the top of the vessel and air is pumped out from this hole.

will the level of water rise

[image: Sketch of closed container]

apparently, the level of water doesn't always rise

I thought since there is no atmospheric pressure:

$$  P_{atm} + DgH_1=DgH_2$$

thus causing the level to rise

Comment: please don't mind the bad drawing

Comment: Re, "...thus causing the level to rise." I think that there is another possibility that you have not considered; which is, that as you decrease the ambient pressure at the surface of the water, that causes the pressure at the bottom of the container to decrease by an equal amount.

Comment: hey but according to some source ig it necessarily does not rise and I want to know why

Comment: Why would you _expect_ it to rise? If you expect it to rise because of that equation, I am suggesting a different interpretation of the equation that does not require the water level to rise.

Comment: ohhh  can i get to know about the other equation ?? do u have any idea @SolomonSLow

Comment: I'm not talking about any _other_ equation.  I'm going to confess, I don't really understand yours, but I _think_ it's meant to tell you that the pressure at some depth within a container equals the pressure at the top (that's probably your Patm), plus pressure due to the weight of the water above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The water level will not rise, it will actually gradually fall. This is because since there is no air pressure, the water molecules can easily escape the liquid and turn into water vapor which gradually fills the vacuum. If the container is sealed after creating the vacuum, it will fall until a certain level and then stop, because it will create an equilibrium where the number of water molecules evaporating from the liquid water will be equal to the number of water vapor molecules reentering the liquid water. If the container is not sealed then it will keep falling until there is no liquid water left.

Comment: thanks but whats the difference between this and the candle experiment

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LOQObaAo8GM&ab_channel=RooHaran

Comment: can u chec this out???

Comment: I see what you are talking about. In the candle experiment, it is actually air pressure outside the glass that is pushing the liquid water up in order to fill the vacuum. This is possible because one part of the water outside the glass is initially in contact with the atmosphere, unlike in an enclosed box here, where there is no difference in pressure acting on the water.

Comment: ohh ok thanks i get it now

Comment: thanks everyone!!!!

Comment: sure, glad to help

Answer (score 2):

Are you thinking of a U shaped tube, where if you decrease the pressure on one side, pressure on the other forces the fluid to rise?

[image]

Image from [Physics Libretexts](https://phys.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/University_Physics/Book%3A_University_Physics_(OpenStax)/Map%3A_University_Physics_I_-_Mechanics_Sound_Oscillations_and_Waves_(OpenStax)/14%3A_Fluid_Mechanics/14.04%3A_Measuring_Pressure)

You can see how pressing on one side would make the fluid move. In the case you have shown, pressing on the top of the fluid just squeezes it.

Comment: so does vaccum not cause water level to rise

Comment: i just wanna know the reason

Comment: Air presses down on the surface of the water. If you take out the air, it stops pressing down. Think of putting an object in the vessel instead of water. Suppose you press on the object, and then stop. Would you expect the object to rise?

Comment: ohh thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

What you will see happen is the water will start to boil.

Comment: does the water lvl rise

Comment: isnt this like the candle experiment???

Comment: what is the "candle experiment"

Answer (score 0):

There are actually some counter-acting phenomena at play here.

1. **No compressibility**: in a first approximation, the water can be considered as incompressible. Then we come to the conclusion that the water starting to vaporize for reduced vessel pressure.
2. More in detail, the **water density changes with temperature**, and the evaporation will cool the water down, which will increase its density, and hence lower the water level further (at least, if it was initially above approx 4degC). if it was below 4degC, then cooling it will initially decrease the density.
3. Also, **water isn't completely incompressible**, and lowering the vessel pressure will lead to an (albeit small) expansion. The question whether this expansion will
   outweigh the vaporization depends a lot on the shape of the vessel. Say, the effects could be strong enough, if you have a long thin tube, that is only open on one end, like this (yes, we're maintaining picture quality here.. :) ) :

[image: long thin pipe vessel]